# Insert data into entity programmatically

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I've installed [contact storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module, it's provide storage for Contact messages which are fully-fledged entities in Drupal 8.
What I want to do, is to insert data programmatically from my custom module into the entity of the contact storage

Comment: Sounds straightforward enough, where are you stuck? What does your code so far look like? Please edit it into the question so we can get an idea of the problem

Answer (score 4):

Yep. Just use any of the methods available to create the entity and save it.

```
use Drupal\contact\Entity\Message;

$message = Message::create([
    // And other fields required...
    'subject' => 'Subject',
    'message' => 'Message...',
    'recipient' => 1,
]);
$message->save();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but when I used this, I got this error Missing bundle for entity type contact_message in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doCreate()

Comment: It's solved now, it was missing the bundle type, thanks so much john

Comment: @MohamedOsamaGbril What did you have for the bundle?

Comment: @Hugo I've added bundle type before required fields like this  `Message::create([
          'contact_form' => 'feedback',
          'subject' => '.......',
          'name'=> ......,
          'mail' => ...........,
          'message' => '......',
    ]);`